# Java Netbeans circular dependency in included project

Tags: java, netbeans, dependency-management

I am using Netbeans 8.0, Java 1.7 and Excelsior Jet 9. I have a project dependency issue with an existing project. Project A (main project) has some extendable classes while Project B is extending some of these classes. I am dynamically loading classes of Project B from Project A. But, I have to copy the project B dependencies in class path (fair enough though Project A has all the dependencies resolved in its own ../lib folder). 
Problem is that complete Project A jar file is required to be in the the class path as well. I am using Excelsior JET to compile Project A to native code (to avoid code forgery) and trying to use Project B (just compiling with Java compiler and using its jar file in class path)as sort of a driver framework. 
With this scheme i may not have to compile the complete project every time after addition of new drivers. 
But with this circular dependency i can't use this scheme (can't expose my ProjectA.jar file). Am I doing something wrong or is this a Java/ classpath limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the only question you actually asked, yes you are doing something wrong and this is not a Java/classpath limitation.

B is trying to extend classes from A, and A is also trying to load classes from B. This cannot be done.

You need to either

1. Combine A and B into one project
2. Remove the shared code from one of the projects (e.g. the classes from A that B needs) and put them in another project, C, on which both A and B depend.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Actually I have only one Project i.e. Project A in production but I always have to compile Project A when a new driver class is added which is the problem. Project A has the class loader which dynamically loads classes from Project B. Project A also has classes which Project B needs to extend to write new Driver classes. How can this be managed with Project C? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do number 2 from my answer. "Project A also has classes which Project B needs" - you need to move these classes into Project C to avoid the circular dependency. Make sure C does not depend on A or B. Now you are free to have A and B depend on C.

Comment: I think i am understanding what you are saying. Let me check and will get back. Bundle of thanks.